# Using a socket in Openshift

Tags: sockets, udp, openshift

I am using Apache Tomcat that runs a webpage for the users. The server also opens a socket in UDP port 14550 to communicate with the devices. The system is working fine in my local computer. When I host the server in openshift, the server does not responds to the messages in the port 14550.

I have tried with differents ports such as 15001 and 8080. Everything works in localhost but not in openstack :(

Can you please help me in fixing this problem.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know(After some researches OFC). Openshift allow only HTTP servers to run on the Openshift Nodes, since HTTP works over TCP/IP connections. You can't use UDP to connect to Openshift nodes. I hope this answers your question.